# Get DCT values from image

Tags: dct

I am pretty new to everything related to image processing so please have that in mind. I have been trying to understand how to get the DCT dc coefficients of luminance blocks from an image. I have read some stuf from here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform#DCT-I and other sources but i am not sure i got it. So if we have an RGB image and we can get all the red, green, blue values from it how can we use them to get the DCT(m,n) where m,n the position of the each pixel?

Comment: It depends, normaly you should convert RGB to YCrCb first. Then calc 8x8 dct on every 8x8 block of Y (luminance) channel separately.

Comment: Ok i agree. Can you give an example or something for how the first pixel's DCT will be calculated?

Comment: X[0][0] is just average of all 8x8 values (because all elements of dct transform matrix for [0][0] are equal).

Comment: Are you trying to get them from the image itself or from the image file?